# Can't change font for headings (CSS, Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting learning HTML and CSS, and I'm running into a problem here.

I'm using Bootstrap for my page, and this is what I've got so far, simplified:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.css:**

```
h, p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

The text in `<p>` shows up just fine as Times New Roman, but the text in `<h3>` refuses to change.

Why is this, and how can I fix it? Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Comment: It should be **h3**, not `h`

Comment: You have to declare the full tag in `CSS`: `h3, p { }`.

Comment: better learn `css` first and start to style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put it as:

```
h3, p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

All the tags and classes should be giving in the full tag name. If you wanna declare the rule to all the **hX** tags like you wanted, you need to give this way:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

There are totally `h1` till `h6` tags.

**Snippet**

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
h3, p {font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed it to `h3, p {` now, but it still isn't working. Changing it to `.div h3, p {`, however, did make it Times New Roman, but I don't see why that's the case only for `h3` and not `p`.

Comment: If you are sure all the elements inside your div will have the same font-family a more compressed version is just to set the font-family of your div. `.div { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; }`

Comment: You need to give both: `.div h3, .div p` or just `.div`. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: What I'm saying is that although the `p` works just fine by itself, the `h3` for some reason needs the `.div` along with it to work. I'm trying to make all `h3` text on the page Times New Roman, and `.div h3` only targets the `h3` in that specific block.

Comment: @user3932000 Nopes, that doesn't happen if you add your custom CSS after loading bootstrap CSS. Check above updated answer. Also learn about CSS specificity.

Comment: @user3932000 Do you mind accepting the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It still doesn't work for me, and the main.css does come after the Bootstrap one in my index.html. I'm not sure what's causing this, but I temporarily included the full code in the original post if you'd like to test it.

Comment: @user3932000 Do you wanna have all the headings in the serif font?

Comment: @PraveenKumar That's odd, it doesn't work on my end. I'm using Liveweave to write it, and I'm using Firefox on Mac OS X to test it; could that be causing the problem? And I'd like all `h3` level headings in serif, not all headings.

Comment: @PraveenKumar How do I check if I have the font? But even if I didn't, shouldn't the `serif` argument at the end take care of that and use another serif font instead?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of how the plunker displays for you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Never mind, it works now. I think it's a problem exclusive with using Liveweave, since typing the whole thing into notepad documents and running it that way made everything be Times New Roman as I wanted. Anyways, thanks for helping me through all this :P

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Praveen's answer:

Every element selector in CSS (that's the thing you type before the `{` on every rule) must match an element on the html page. There are three possible selectors, and all 3 are used in this html element:

```
<h3 class="header-3" id="page-title">Test</h3>
```

These are:

- h3, the element itself
- header-3, the class
- page-title, the id

To select these, you'd select them as following in CSS:

```
h3 { color: red; }
.header-3 { color: red; }
#page-title { color: red; }
```

Comment: Ah... You are taking class for him, which he's already doing. `:P` He should learn all these by himself.